# UITextView contentSize.height larger than necessary?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitextview, contentsize

`UITextView` scrolls even when all the text fits within its frame. It scrolls as if there are two new lines at the bottom of the text, but there aren't. So, its `contentSize.height` seems to be a couple lines larger than the text. How do I get rid of this? I.e., how do I tighten up the content size?

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem. I noticed the difference on space gets bigger as the length of the text on the UITextView grows.

Comment: UITextView has a fixed 8px margin in all directions which usually accounts for many of the sizing anomalies when using this control.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up the contentSize for that UITextView so that it tightens to the text.

You can make use of NSString methods named sizeWithFont.... You can check full list here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html

I've noticed some issues working with some of them, but one that never fails me is:

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size
```

I suppose you have a fixed width and want to find out the correct height. Considering a fixed 200px width, it would be something like:

```
NSString *myText = @"Some text...";
CGSize tightContentSize = [mytext sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(200, 10000000)].height;

[myTextView setContentSize:tightContentSize];
```

Take into consideration that your UITextView has an 8px padding in all directions, so if your UITextView frame is 200 width, you would actualy have a 184px width for text.

Answer (score 0):

It's late but, for other people, try with:

```
self.textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

That's work for me.